# cant connect database server using ip address

Tags: php, mysql, linux, system-administration

I am using PHP and MySQL to make a database connection , problem is :

the web application project in my local machine when am trying connect to database remote server every thing is work fine

```
mysql_connect("x.xx.xx.x","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
```

when i deploy the web application in the remote server that have the mysql database and try to use that web application am getting no database error connection !! if i change database connection to :

```
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
```

using localhost (127.0.0.1) instead of using ip address ever thing work fine , i have tried check /etc/my.conf file and add bind-address=192.168.15.15 and restart mysql server 
still cant connect to database 

any idea !!!

Comment: 192.168.15.15 , is the ip address of remote server

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check two things.  First, make sure the port `3306` is open for connections.  Second, if you're connecting remotely, you'll need to create a wildcard user (The host will be a percentage sign `%`).  Take a look at the `mysql.user` table. If the user you're trying to connect to has a `Host` of `localhost`, you won't be able to connect remotely.

To create a new user:

`CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Give that user permissions, I suggest to only the database in question:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_database.* TO 'newuser'@'%';
```

Finally, reload the privileges:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: as i said am able to connect to remote server through my local machine , after deploy the wep application in same server am not able connect to database (which is in the same server) while am using the ip address , when i use (localhost) every thing is work fine , ok , iahve create the user as you said still getting same problem !!

Answer (score 0):

problem was i was enabling the SElinux , so i enabled httpd network with commad :

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```